# Linked ARM Templates failing

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Linked ARM Template for API management failing

I deployed each template individually in sequence in the same sequence as they are deployed successfully.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "instanceTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "url for template",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "sku": { "value": "[parameters('APIManagementSku')]" },
          "skuCount": { "value": "[parameters('APIManagementSkuCapacity')]" },
          "publisherName": { "value": "[parameters('publisherName')]" },
          "publisherEmail": { "value": "[parameters('publisherEmail')]" }
        }
      }
    },        
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "productsUsersTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "url for template",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "apiManagementServiceName": { "value": "[parameters('APIManagementInstanceName')]" }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'instanceTemplate')]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "seviceTagsTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "url for template",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "apiManagementServiceName": { "value": "[parameters('APIManagementInstanceName')]" }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'instanceTemplate')]"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I expect the template to be correctly deployed (As they do when deploying them individually).
However, I get the following error message:

```
Conflict: {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "PreconditionFailed",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"PreconditionFailed\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Management.Core.Exceptions.PreconditionFailedException' was thrown.\",\r\n    \"details\": null\r\n  }\r\n}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also tried adding additional dependencies but I still get the same error

Comment: this question gives no data to help you out. what is in the linked templates?

Comment: The linked templates consist of the following in the order they are defined: **1. Api management instance(Microsoft.ApiManagement/service) 2. products users,groups and subscriptions (Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users, Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products, Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products/groups,Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions), 3. authorization server (Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/authorizationServers) 4. service tags (Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/tags). **.

Comment: thats not helpful. add template(s) content to the question, please

Comment: each linked template is over 500 lines long.. and it contains a lot of information which if I mask won't be any good. I did mention that I am able to deploy individual template without facing any problems. That's the reason why I think that there could be an issue with the way I've structured the master template...

Comment: probably something wrong with ordering or how you split them

Comment: there's nothing obvious in the master template - posting the templates on gist or similar would be helpful.  If you have a trackingId we can look at the logs internally to see of there's more there...